# Custom tick locations on Pandas datetime plot axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot

I have a plot in Pandas with dates on the x-axis and some number on the y-axis. I want to set the x-axis ticks on specific dates. I can't figure out how. For instance, given this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range('1946-06-07', '1967-03-15', freq='M')
y = np.random.random(len(x))

d = pd.DataFrame({'month': x, 'value': y})
d.plot()
```

How do I set the x-ticks to some specified set of ticks, say 1949, 1950, 1954 and 1960, instead of the automatic regularly spaced ticks? If only regularly spaced ticks are possible, how can I specify the first of them so that for instance it starts at 1949 and then goes on in 5 year intervals?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I did not consider the most obvious solution. This works like a charm:

```py
locations = ['1948-7-7', '1952-6-25', '1956-6-13', '1959-3-12', '1963-5-15']
labels = locations
plt.xticks(locations, labels)
```